# T-SQL Case statement fails in oddly specific circumstance

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, view, casting, case

I have an issue involving a Self-referential temporary table, a stored procedure, and a view.

I use a stored procedure to dynamically generate sql that will return results based on filters the user selects on a web page. One thing the user can do is search for a lake based on what drainage it's in. So, if a drainage A is searched for, we have to include all of its children in the search as well, since a Lake only knows its most immediate drainage.

When a list of drainages is searched, the proc creates the following

```
WITH DrainageHeirarchy AS
        (
        SELECT d.DrainageID, d.DrainageDesc, d.ParentDrainageID
        FROM Drainage d
        WHERE d.DrainageID IN (161)
        UNION ALL
        SELECT d.DrainageID, d.DrainageDesc, d.ParentDrainageID
        FROM Drainage d
        JOIN DrainageHeirarchy ON d.ParentDrainageID = DrainageHeirarchy.DrainageID
        )
```

*Note that in this case, the 161 is just a comma-delimited list of drainage ids the user is filtering on.

Now, we want to pull information from a view that has data on the lakes. so the proc generates the following select statement.

```
select DISTINCT
    l.Year1stStocked
from dbo.vwlakeextended l
WHERE DrainageID IN (SELECT DrainageID FROM DrainageHeirarchy)
```

*Note that I've removed a lot of other fields that it pulls down, and some other checks in the where clause that don't seem to be causing any issues, for simplicity.

The case where the user selects Drainage 161 is special in that it causes an error. To understand this first, we have to see how the view dbo.vwlakeextended generates the field. It does so with the following.

```
case when isnumeric(l.Year1stStocked)=0 or l.Year1stStocked is null
   then (select cast(min(s.stockyear) as varchar(255)) from stk.stocking s where replace(SiteCode, ' ', '') = replace(l.lakecode, ' ', ''))
   else case when isnull(               
                            (select min(s.stockyear)
                             from stk.stocking s
                             where replace(SiteCode, ' ', '') = replace(l.lakecode, ' ', ''))
                                     ,year(getdate())
                         ) < l.Year1stStocked
            then (select cast(min(s.stockyear) as varchar(255)) from stk.stocking s where replace(SiteCode, ' ', '') = replace(l.lakecode, ' ', ''))
            else l.Year1stStocked
        end
end as Year1stStocked,
```

Effectively what is is doing is generating the number from another table if a year isn't given in our source table. The source table uses a varchar(255) to store the year, or a descriptor in the event that it's not known (not optimal, but besides the point).

The point at which the error occurs in when the comparison < l.Year1stStocked occurs. Interestingly enough, this should only happen in the event that isnumeric(l.Year1stStocked)=0 or l.Year1stStocked is null, so the comparison shouldn't be a problem.

I've checked the issues with isnumeric() in that it passes numeric related characters (+, -, $, etc.) through, but the string it's failing on is '?', which is in the data, and returns 0 on isnumeric()

### Why It Really Bugs Me

In this case, the temp table returns a list of three ids: 161,162, and 163.

If I replace the subquery with those id's, everything works just fine.
If I replace the column DrainageID with the number 161, it works fine.

In any case, the view should not have any issue converting '?' to an int, because it should never have the opportunity to. I don't know why in this case, it does.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it works when you hardcode `161` then this can't be your problem row. Look at the query plan maybe it evaluates the case expression on another row which contains the problematic characters you have already mentioned before it does the semi join on the temp table for the `in`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to make a suggestion:

I'm not sure how that descriptor can be populated but I would parse the descriptor field for that row for any white-space characters like char(11) which when passed to is numeric() results in a false positive:

```
declare @v varchar(10);
set @v = CHAR(11);
select isnumeric(@v);
select @v;
```

This would rule out any other causes that might not be normally visible.

CHAR(9), 10, 11, 12 & 13 etc return 1

Comment: I was worried about getting a false positive, but the piece of data that is throwing the error is '?'. I checked that and it is correctly returning 0 for the isnumeric() method, but only in the circumstance described in the post :(.